# Free Text Query for Sharepoint 2007 Search

Tags: sharepoint-search

Hi I'm working on Sharepoint 2007 and I'm stuck at a place in free text query where i need to fetch only those records where my multilookup column is either null or empty.
Could you help he out with this as i'm not able to do it.